# Pdf File does not display text correctly when sent over socket connection

Tags: java, android

I'm sending a pdf file from my java server to an android client. However when I look at the pdf file on the phone, the text is sometimes wrong (just some random symbols). Does someone know what is causing that problem?

Here is the code of the server:

```
private void sendPdfToPhone(File pdf) {
    try {
        InputStream iS = new FileInputStream(pdf);
        DataOutputStream dOS = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

        String filename = pdf.getName();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) pdf.length()];

        dOS.writeUTF(filename);
        dOS.writeLong(bytes.length);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        int bytesSent = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = iS.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            dOS.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesSent += bytesRead;
        }
        dOS.close();
        logger.debug("Sent file " + filename + " to Client: " + bytesSent + " / " + bytes.length);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.fatal(ex);
    }

}
```

And this is the code of the Android client:

```
int bytesRead;
String filename = dIS.readUTF();
long fileSize = dIS.readLong();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

File pdf = new File(context.getCacheDir() + "/" + filename);
if (!pdf.exists()) {
  pdf.createNewFile();
  FileOutputStream fOS = new FileOutputStream(pdf);

  while (fileSize > 0 && (bytesRead = dIS.read(buffer, 0, (int) 
   Math.min(buffer.length, fileSize))) != -1) {
   fOS.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   fileSize -= bytesRead;
 }

 dIS.close();
 dOut.close();
}
pdfFile = pdf;
socket.close();
return pdf;
```

Comment: Have you checked the contents of file by sending it over by some other mechanism. Mail it to your gmail account. For all you know it may be because some of the fonts are missing on mobile.

Comment: I don't think that that is the problem, because it does work like 1 out of 3 times. Then everythink looks perfectly fine. That's why I am confused.

Comment: @VinayAvasthi I've looked at the file on th computer and it does look different than on the phone but the text is only some random symbols